# Does this sequence of polynomials have a name?

Tags: calculus, polynomials

I'm very interested in the function $$f : (0,\infty) \rightarrow (0,\infty)$$ $$x \mapsto - \log(1-e^{-x}).$$

When I use Wolfram alpha to compute the $n$th derivatives of $f$, I find that there exists a sequence of polynomials $P_1,P_2,\ldots$ such that for $n \geq 1$ we have $$f^{(n)}(x) = \frac{e^x}{(1-e^x)^n}P_n(e^x).$$

For example:

$$\frac{d^6}{dx^6}(-\log(1 - e^{-x})) = \frac{e^x}{(1-e^x)^6} (1+26 e^x + 66 e^{2 x} + 26 e^{3 x} + e^{4 x})$$

> **Question.** Is there a name for this sequence of polynomials?

If these polynomials don't have a name, I'd also be satisfied with a name for the variant on Pascal's triangle whose entries are the coefficients of these polynomials.

Comment: That looks like an Eulerian polynomial: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_number

Comment: I will conjecture that we can describe the polynomials $P_n$ with a three term recurrence relation.  Have you tried to work something like that out?

Comment: @hardmath, no, but I'm very interested!

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, I think you're right!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Lord Shark the Unknown](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/436618/lord-shark-the-unknown) is spot on.

[WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx((e%5Ex%2F(1-e%5Ex)%5En)+P(e%5Ex))) tells us that
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\frac{e^x}{(1-e^x)^n} P(e^x)
=
\frac{e^x}{(1-e^x)^{n+1}} Q(e^x)
$$
where
$$
Q(t)=(t-t^2)P'(t)+((n-1)t+1)P(t)
$$
Therefore,
$$
P_{n+1}(t)=(t-t^2)P_n'(t)+((n-1)t+1)P_n(t)
$$
Since $P_2=A_1$, we have $P_n=A_{n-1}$, where $A_n$ is the $n$-th [Eulerian polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_number).